# Django templates: accessing the previous and the following element of the list

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am rather new to django templates and have an impression that I have not understood some basics.

I have a list of elements and I need to render an element of the list based on conditions against the the previous and the next elements (in case the following or the previous elements are hidden, I need to mark the current element as border element).

How can I reference the previous and the following elements within a `for` loop in Django templates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could [write a custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for `next` and `previous`:

```
def next(value, arg):
    try:
        return value[int(arg)+1]
    except:
        return None
```

and in the template:

```
{% for ... %}
  {% with list|next:forloop.counter0 as next %}
    {% if next.is_hidden %}
    ...
    {% endif %} 
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

but like others have said, there are probably more elegants solutions doing this via your view

Comment: that was my first thought, and it anyway looks like a useful utility =)

Comment: if you want to get the next item should it not be +1 in the template tag?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this strictly with built-in template tags. You need to involve some Python.

One method would be to `zip` the list with itself:

```
new = ([(None, orig[0], orig[1])] + 
       zip(orig, orig[1:], orig[2:]) + 
       [(orig[-2], orig[-1], None)])
```

and pass that to the template, then loop over it like this:

```
{% for prev, current, next in new %}
    {% if prev.hidden or next.hidden %}
        BORDER
    {% endif %}
    {{ current }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use the Django templates for this kind of logic. You have your views to handle it. I would figure out which elements of the list are borders and pass in an extra parameter that I can handle in the template using a simple `if` statement. For example:

```
{% for element,is_border in data.items %}
 {% if is_border %}
   do something
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

There are tons of similar ways you can do this. I presented just one example.

Comment: this is a purely presentation issue, I would not like to make the analysis outside templates

Comment: Then you can use the presenter programming paradigm where you have a data manipulation layer as your final step before handing stuff over to templates. Templates really should remain dumb. Django makes an exception and actually allows a little more logic and control in its templating engine than others.

Comment: You can think of the presenter as a final 'data validator and packager' for display purposes.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are talking about, but I am not a fan of breeding abstraction layers until they are really needed =) Templates could handle the issue without any problems, anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

You can create an external tag which does that but django templating system which was build to be lightweight has no such feature in for loops.